# Favicon not showing up for the first time

Tags: angularjs, favicon

I have build an AngularJS Single Page Application and it works fine, but it has one problem: when the website loads for the first time, the favicon does not appear. If I reload the page, it finally shows up. It works the same on every web browser where I have tested: Mozilla Firefox, Chrome, Chromium, IE 9, Android browser, Safari for iPhone.

This is the common part of the SPA:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="vannApp" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="Vanntile Ianito" name="author">
    <base href="file:///home/vanntile/Documents/doc/WEB_DEVELOPING/Vann_Original/index.html">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="icon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="icon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="icon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="icon/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="icon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="icon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="icon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="icon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icon/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon/favicon-194x194.png" sizes="194x194">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="manifest" href="icon/manifest.json">

    <title>Website Title</title>

    <link href="css/vannstyle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <p>This is some text. I could have thought of something better, but I'm lazy.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The favicons are made with [Real favicon Generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). And the Microsoft tiles are made with: [Windows 8.1 tile](http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com/en). They are not in the root of the website but in **/icon**.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It defers from browser to browser. It's expected behavior

Comment: But it has the same behaviour on all of the above browsers...

Comment: Try placing the favicon in the root directory (`/favicon.ico` instead of `icon/favicon.ico`), change your code accordingly, clear your browser's cache, and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have put the **favicon.ico** meta tag the first from the favicon meta tags. Check the google page as an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="vannApp" >
<head>
   <meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image">
   <link href="/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the favicon is not placed in the root of the site. Try changing their folder and see if it still happens.

Comment: Agreed.  Name it `favicon.ico` and put it in the root directory.  Browsers automatically know to look for that file in the root even without a link reference.