# settin up favicon in angular js application

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to link my favicon but nothing seems to work.  I have the icon saved as "favicon.ico" in the same directory as "index.html" and am calling it as such in the  tag.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: open you browser dev tools and see if it gives a `Not Found Error` and if it does then your  `href` is not pointing to that icon

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713360/favicon-not-showing-up-for-the-first-time

Comment: favicon must be in root directory and check the format once

Comment: This is the exact code I am using and the href does work.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="favicon.ico"  rel="shortcut icon" />

Comment: use <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> and clear cache

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing the path pointing to the favicon.

In my case it is as follows

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/home_favicon.ico">`