# Favicon icon is not displaying in IE browser for Angular 6 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

Tags: internet-explorer, angular6, favicon

I am using an angular 6 project. In Index.html added a link for favicon and image stored in the root folder.

```
rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"
```

It is showing in other browsers but in the IE browser not able to see the favicon icon. Tried to add

```
rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"
```

but not able to see. Then tried

```
rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{baseUrl}}/favicon.ico"
```

If I add the base URL with the favicon it is showing but only if I refresh the page. And if I redirect to another new page it is not showing, again if I refresh then displaying. Don't know why it is happening. Is it only related to Angular or something else? Please try to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Favicon not showing up for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713360/favicon-not-showing-up-for-the-first-time)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in my angular application, it works well, please check it.

code in the index.html page:

```
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

The favicon.ico located in the src folder. And I add the favicon.ico path in the assets node in the angular.json file (the build and test node).

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "augular6-sample": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/augular6-sample",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"              
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "augular6-sample:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "augular6-sample:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "augular6-sample:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
```

**Edit**:

Besides, you could also try to add an image in the assets folder, then try to use the following code:

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/Capture.PNG">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. But this is not working at all for me, I have already tried this. It is just showing the IE icon.

Comment: Try to clear the browser cache and cookie, then recheck whether it works well.

Comment: Besides, you could also try to add an image in the assets folder, then try to use the following code:

      `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/Capture.PNG">`